# Interrupt handler declaration: armcc vs gcc

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, interrupt-handling, armcc

I want to declare an interrupt routine function.

Originally written for armcc as :

```
extern "C" __irq void System_FiqDispatcher() SECTION_SRAM_2;
```

I am writing the same as:

```
extern "C" __attribute__ (( interrupt("IRQ"))) void System_FiqDispatcher() SECTION_SRAM_2;
```

I got the following error: `line XXX : Error:  #1207-D: attribute "interrupt" ignored.`
What could be the problem?

Comment: I am compiling this using GNU GCC

Comment: Why did you give it that attribute?  Is that something GCC understands, even?

Comment: I was throwing some error...let me check

Comment: A-J, please, add full error message from GCC to the question. "Error 1207" is from armcc.

Comment: HwSystemMain.h:1168:12: error: '__irq' does not name a type...make[3]: *** [C:/code_coverage.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Comment: @A-J, but you just said you changed that.  Your supposed GCC example doesn't even have that `__irq` string in it at all!

Comment: Well I got it resolved..Thanks osgx..I realized my mistake! I was compiling some part with armcc and the rest with gnu gcc...Just added a switch and now it is working fine! :-)

Comment: Why did you tag this as C while using `extern "C"`? Are you compiling this in C or C++?